# PDI: how to handle many rows as a single xml value

Tags: soap, pentaho, etl, kettle

I have to handle these steps:

```
- order (table input)
  - id

- order row (table input)
  - order_id
  - row_id
  - product_id
  - quantity

- a soap web service to call
```

I have to execute the soap web service for every order passing all the order's rows for the given order.

For example, if I have 3 orders I must execute the web service 3 times and at every execution I must pass to the soap web service all the order's rows as xml argument like this:

```
<rows>
  <item>
    <order_id>1</order_id>
    <row_id>1</row_id>
    <product_id>123</product_id>
    <quantity>12</quantity>
  </item>
  <item>
    <order_id>1</order_id>
    <row_id>2</row_id>
    <product_id>456</product_id>
    <quantity>65</quantity>
  </item>
  ... and so on...
</rows>
```

I cannot figure out how to design the trasformation so it can executes the soap web service for each single order passing all the order's rows as xml single value.

Any help ? (many thanks in advance...)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like u need to look on examples which are distributed with data-integration package.

Look into $KETTLE_HOME/sample/transformations/transformation-executor

2 helpful steps are "Get rows from result" and "Copy rows to result" will let u manage your needs.

Comment: Ok, I've seen the example but I don't understand how to collect all the rows to create a single xml. I've tried with an xml output but it creates the xml for every single row...

Answer (score 0):

Same.

Look inside of example directory and find "XML Join - Create a multilayer XML file".

But there are another ways to solve problem. U can just dump all fragments to xml file and then load file again in next transformation.

Comment: I've tried to create the first (parent trasformation) that calls the child trasformation using a "trasformation executor" step, the parent trasformation calls the child transformation for every order (all good). The child transformation then "get rows" (order id) and filter the order rows with a "table input" step, here I've tried to write all the rows with an "xml output" step. The parent transformation then loads the xml file but if I print  the content it is different from the content of the xml file, seems like that the 2 trasformations has been executed asyncronously...

Comment: You a right. Transformations ment to be executed in parallel (asyncronously).